# text alignment / swiftUi

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

swiftui i am learning new. I couldn't align my brain stopped. In the picture I said how I wanted to do this. Can you help?

[image]

```
  HStack{
                Text("Picture")
                    .font(.custom("Pacifico-Regular",size: 50))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .shadow(color: .white, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
                    
                    Image("1coin").resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width:30, height: 30)
                    Text("123")
                        .font(.custom("Pacifico-Regular",size: 20))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible layout (with some replicated components instead of your custom). Prepared with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
    HStack{
        Spacer()
        Text("Picture")
            .font(.custom("Pacifico-Regular",size: 50))
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .shadow(color: .white, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
        Spacer().overlay(
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "1.circle").resizable()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width:30, height: 30)
                Text("123")
                    .font(.custom("Pacifico-Regular",size: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
        , alignment: .trailing)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ZStack` to embed two `HStacks` and align them separately.
They will be displayed on top of each other.

You align "Picture" text to the middle - it happens by default.
And then align second HStack with `Spacer()`

```
ZStack {
    HStack{
        Text("Picture")
        .font(.custom("Pacifico-Regular",size: 50))
        .background(Color.red)
        .padding()
        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
    }
    HStack {
         Spacer()
         Image("1coin").resizable()
         .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
         .frame(width:30, height: 30)
         .background(Color.red)
         Text("123")
         .font(.custom("Pacifico-Regular",size: 20))
         .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

If you want to keep all elements at the top, you will need another `VStack` + `Spacer` on top of ZStack:

```
VStack {
    ZStack {
        HStack{
        Text("Picture")
            .font(.custom("Pacifico-Regular",size: 50))
            .background(Color.red)
            .padding()
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
        }
        
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Image("1coin").resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width:30, height: 30)
                .background(Color.red)
            Text("123")
                .font(.custom("Pacifico-Regular",size: 20))
                .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
    Spacer()
}
```

Comment: I want the picture to rotate around itself like a planet, not clockwise. How can I do it? "1coin" image. do you know about this